# How to use Slider Revolution tag names in a React / JSX component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, revolution-slider

I have following coponent:

```js
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <main className="site-main">
            <rs-fullwidth-wrap
                id="rev_slider_2_1_forcefullwidth"
                style={{ marginTop: '0px', marginBottom: '0px' }}
            >
```

got this:

> Property 'rs-fullwidth-wrap' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

I tried to add this before return

```js
declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        'rs-fullwidth-wrap': any
        'rs-module-wrap': any
    }
}
```

Did not help. What else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration is incorrect, try this:

```
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      "rs-fullwidth-wrap": JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"];
    }
  }
}
```